# WIN32 C, how to check if a virtual key is a character?

Tags: winapi

VK_LEFT is not a character but VK_A is.
How can I differentiate them?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure there is a really clean way to do this, but try looking at [ToAscii](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646316%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [ToAsciiEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646318%28v=vs.85%29.aspx): if you get a 0 then it is a control character like VK_LEFT.